# Invite Bot to voice channel without using ctx

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I was wondering if there was a way to make a bot join vc if there is one member in a specific voice channel. I don't want the user to use a command to activate this though.

```
async def arrive(ctx):
bruh = client.get_channel(748685131119591506)
curMembers = []
for member in bruh.members:
    curMembers.append(member)
channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
vc = await channel.connect()
boi = len(curMembers)
room = discord.Object(748685131119591506)
if boi == 1 and room: 
    await ctx.send("Dang everyone left :pensive:")
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
elif boi == 1:
    await vc.move_to(room)


@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def looparrive(ctx):
    client.loop.create_task(arrive(ctx))
```

This arrive code is attached to a `client.command()` because I don't know how to pass context any other way. This bot only needs to work on one server so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar to this:

```
async def arrive():
    guild = client.get_guild(GUILDID)
    text_channel = client.get_channel(TEXTCHANNELID)
    voice_channels = guild.voice_channels
    for vc in voice_channels:
        if len(vc.members) == 1:
            vClient = await vc.connect()
            await text_channel.send("Dang everyone left :pensive:")
            await vClient.disconnect()


@tasks.loop(seconds=50)
async def looparrive():
    await arrive()
```

A 5 second loop seems a bit aggressive, so I suggest upping that to avoid this process getting massively spammed.